# C# String Interpolation: Repeat Format Token

Tags: c#, formatting, string-interpolation

In C#, I am trying to format 10 numbers (double variables).
The first two are to be formatted in one way, the remaining eight in a second format.

For example:

```
string format = "{0,15:F9}, {1,15:F9}, {2,15:E6}, {3,15:E6}, {4,15:E6}, {5,15:E6}, {6,15:E6}, {7,15:E6}, {8,15:E6}, {9,15:E6}";
```

And then:

```
string myFormattedString = String.Format(format, x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9);
```

Is there a simpler way to apply/repeat the same formatting (alignment, numeric precision) to multiple indices without explicitly including a separate `{}` format token for each element?

Comment: Build it with linq perhaps? `new [x0, x1, ...].Select(x => x.ToString("0,15:F9"))` and then just `string.Join` the result